# Adding several attachments to one feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qfield, attachments

I want to add several files (for instance JPEG, DWG, PNG, etc.) as attachments in one polygon attribute field.

I created a new field with widget Type - Attachment. But it allows adding only one file or one folder.

It is possible to do in ArcGIS Pro. But I didn't find the way in QGIS

Comment: As far as I know to make it straightforwardly is impossible, but check this article: https://merginmaps.com/docs/layer/attach-multiple-photos-to-features/ it utilizes [Relations](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations). Would be great if you put an answer to your question afterward :)

Answer (score 1):

I have created 2 layers "Community" and another shapefile "F" with no geometry type
[image]

[image]
in project-> properties I made the relation between them- "attachment"
[image]

then in "community" from the attribute form, I drag and drop the relation to the form layout
[image]

in "F" shapefile in Actions I add this.
[image]

after that, it remains to add the linked folder.
[image]